# How do I execute a php script through a cron job in serversfree?

Tags: php, cron

I tried to make a cron job but it didn't execute the script.

Screenshots here:
[image: Add job]

[image: Error]

What command do I need to execute to make the script execute every 30 minutes?

Thanks

Comment: the image you attached cannot be found :/

Comment: dont post images, post text

Comment: Sorry, I'll re-upload it!

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/qCeh5 - I need at least 10 rep to post images

Comment: Sounds like the file `cron.php` does not exist.

Comment: I have it in my root directory, it does exist

Comment: Do you have access to the command line? If so, can you run that command yourself?

Comment: There's an online SSH web console, is that it?

Comment: What is 'your root directory'? The root of the server is not the right one, but the document root of your site probably neither. I think it is the highest directory you can write into, but it's hard to guess from here.

Comment: It's the highest dir I can write into

Comment: @Smeagol - there, now you have 10 rep.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the images!

Comment: Figured it out!  Thanks to everyone who commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I need to add **public_html** to the command:
 php -f /home/u757823165/**public_html**/cron/save.php